# csrf configuration in Spring Security with Angular

Tags: angular, spring-security, csrf-token

I have an application that is a REST API backend with an Angular frontend.

Now I'd like to configure CSRF for it.

I followed the instructions in this post:

https://kostis.hashnode.dev/csrf-configuration-for-angular-spring-boot-application

Didn't do any code change on Angular as informed in the above article.

Here is the Java Spring code.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    ... 
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {        
        
        http
    .csrf()
    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
    .and()
        ... [rest of security config]
                
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
      CookieCsrfTokenRepository repository = CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse();
      repository.setCookiePath("/");
      return repository;
    }

    
    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {      
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication();
    }
    
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@...
public class MyApiApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApiApplication.class, args);
    }   
    
    
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {        
        
        registry.addMapping("/**")
        .allowedMethods("*")
        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
    }

}
```

But when I run the Angular frontend POST I get a 403 error and mismatching XSRF-TOKEN for header and response.

GET works fine.

Also noticed that in the response headers there are two `Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=`. One empty and one with value.

General

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/myapi
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 403 
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Response Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 18 Apr 2023 18:24:49 GMT
Expires: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=84343778-ty4c-62c5-87u4-63480d83442u; Path=/
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX; Path=/myapi; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oRswGaADCgEAoxIEEAEAAAAJjhxq1SuIJAAAAAA=
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Request Headers

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 40
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=8admwp91-8d6e-4856-9475-80b20ac7e5f2; JSESSIONID=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Logs

```
2023-04-19 10:35:11.291 INFO [background-preinit] [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version.<clinit>(Version.java:21)] - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.2.5.Final
2023-04-19 10:35:11.335 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger.logStarting(StartupInfoLogger.java:55)] - Starting MyapiApplication using Java 11.0.18 on XXXXXX with PID XXXXXX (C:\App\Myappws-Myapi\Myapi\target\classes started by XXXXXXXXXX in C:\App\Myappws-Myapi\Myapi)
2023-04-19 10:35:11.339 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.logStartupProfileInfo(SpringApplication.java:631)] - No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-04-19 10:35:11.394 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.boot.logging.DeferredLog.logTo(DeferredLog.java:255)] - Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-04-19 10:35:11.394 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.boot.logging.DeferredLog.logTo(DeferredLog.java:255)] - For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-04-19 10:35:11.959 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.multipleStoresDetected(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:262)] - Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-04-19 10:35:11.959 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:132)] - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-04-19 10:35:12.034 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:201)] - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 68 ms. Found x JPA repository interfaces.
2023-04-19 10:35:12.159 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.multipleStoresDetected(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:262)] - Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
2023-04-19 10:35:12.160 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:132)] - Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-04-19 10:35:12.173 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.isStrictRepositoryCandidate(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:349)] - Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.mycomp.Myapi.repository.A1Repository; If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
2023-04-19 10:35:12.177 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:201)] - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 17 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
2023-04-19 10:35:12.824 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:108)] - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-04-19 10:35:12.835 INFO [restartedMain] [org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:173)] - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2023-04-19 10:35:12.836 INFO [restartedMain] [org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:173)] - Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-04-19 10:35:12.836 INFO [restartedMain] [org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:173)] - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.70]
2023-04-19 10:35:13.075 INFO [restartedMain] [org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:173)] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-04-19 10:35:13.075 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.prepareWebApplicationContext(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:292)] - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1681 ms
2023-04-19 10:35:13.131 INFO [restartedMain] [waffle.servlet.spi.SecurityFilterProviderCollection.<init>(SecurityFilterProviderCollection.java:65)] - using 'waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider'
2023-04-19 10:35:13.131 INFO [restartedMain] [waffle.servlet.spi.SecurityFilterProviderCollection.<init>(SecurityFilterProviderCollection.java:65)] - using 'waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider'
2023-04-19 10:35:13.202 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean.onStartup(RegistrationBean.java:50)] - Filter negotiateSecurityFilter was not registered (disabled)
2023-04-19 10:35:13.363 INFO [restartedMain] [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper.logPersistenceUnitInformation(LogHelper.java:31)] - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-04-19 10:35:13.412 INFO [restartedMain] [org.hibernate.Version.logVersion(Version.java:44)] - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.14.Final
2023-04-19 10:35:13.570 INFO [restartedMain] [org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager.<clinit>(JavaReflectionManager.java:56)] - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2023-04-19 10:35:13.678 INFO [restartedMain] [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.<init>(Dialect.java:175)] - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2023-04-19 10:35:14.521 INFO [restartedMain] [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:110)] - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-04-19 10:35:14.770 INFO [restartedMain] [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:123)] - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-04-19 10:35:14.951 INFO [restartedMain] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator.initiateService(JtaPlatformInitiator.java:52)] - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-04-19 10:35:14.969 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:437)] - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-04-19 10:35:15.884 WARN [restartedMain] [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration.openEntityManagerInViewInterceptor(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:219)] - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-04-19 10:35:16.302 DEBUG [restartedMain] [org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.process(ExpressionBasedFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource.java:72)] - Adding web access control expression [authenticated] for any request
2023-04-19 10:35:16.639 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.<init>(DefaultSecurityFilterChain.java:55)] - Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@fb14be8, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@ba6aed0, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@67188255, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@548212b9, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@1707b04b, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@304318fb, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@70f99aa8, waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilter@664947c7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@4efcc435, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@2d5324ae, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6ee90a83, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@b1d3a99, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4c95db9c, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3792e418, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@32a494af]
2023-04-19 10:35:17.241 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.OptionalLiveReloadServer.startServer(OptionalLiveReloadServer.java:59)] - LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-04-19 10:35:17.270 INFO [restartedMain] [org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:173)] - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
2023-04-19 10:35:17.301 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:220)] - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/myapi'
2023-04-19 10:35:17.310 INFO [restartedMain] [org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger.logStarted(StartupInfoLogger.java:61)] - Started MyapiApplication in 6.284 seconds (JVM running for 8.033)
2023-04-19 10:35:51.342 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:173)] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-04-19 10:35:51.343 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:525)] - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-04-19 10:35:51.346 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:547)] - Completed initialization in 3 ms
2023-04-19 10:35:51.363 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:218)] - Securing POST /aaa/bbb/ccc/
2023-04-19 10:35:51.372 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:104)] - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.416 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:125)] - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/myapi/aaa/bbb/ccc/
2023-04-19 10:35:51.417 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.handle(AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.java:61)] - Responding with 403 status code
2023-04-19 10:35:51.419 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:357)] - Did not store empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.420 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:357)] - Did not store empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.420 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:120)] - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2023-04-19 10:35:51.427 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:218)] - Securing POST /error
2023-04-19 10:35:51.428 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:104)] - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.435 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)] - Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.436 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:116)] - Request requested invalid session id 9M1A166YTB361D5F6016F3FBJK3C80K5
2023-04-19 10:35:51.452 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:247)] - Failed to authorize filter invocation [POST /error] with attributes [authenticated]
2023-04-19 10:35:51.454 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:357)] - Did not store empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.458 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:357)] - Did not store empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.458 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-1] [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:120)] - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2023-04-19 10:35:51.461 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:218)] - Securing POST /aaa/bbb/ccc/
2023-04-19 10:35:51.462 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:104)] - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.463 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:125)] - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/myapi/aaa/bbb/ccc/
2023-04-19 10:35:51.464 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.handle(AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.java:61)] - Responding with 403 status code
2023-04-19 10:35:51.465 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:357)] - Did not store empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.465 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:357)] - Did not store empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.465 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:120)] - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2023-04-19 10:35:51.466 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:218)] - Securing POST /error
2023-04-19 10:35:51.466 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:104)] - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.662 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:357)] - Did not store empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.665 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:357)] - Did not store empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.665 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-3] [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:120)] - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2023-04-19 10:35:51.668 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:218)] - Securing POST /aaa/bbb/ccc/
2023-04-19 10:35:51.668 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:104)] - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.670 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:125)] - Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/myapi/aaa/bbb/ccc/
2023-04-19 10:35:51.670 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.handle(AccessDeniedHandlerImpl.java:61)] - Responding with 403 status code
2023-04-19 10:35:51.670 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:357)] - Did not store empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.671 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:357)] - Did not store empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:51.671 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:120)] - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2023-04-19 10:35:51.671 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:218)] - Securing POST /error
2023-04-19 10:35:51.671 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:104)] - Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2023-04-19 10:35:52.811 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [waffle.spring.NegotiateSecurityFilter.doFilter(NegotiateSecurityFilter.java:145)] - successfully logged in user: XXXXX\XXXXXXXXXX
2023-04-19 10:35:52.813 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy.onAuthentication(CsrfAuthenticationStrategy.java:63)] - Replaced CSRF Token
2023-04-19 10:35:53.295 WARN [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log(DirectJDKLog.java:173)] - Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [476] milliseconds.
2023-04-19 10:35:53.299 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.createNewSessionIfAllowed(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:410)] - Created HttpSession as SecurityContext is non-default
2023-04-19 10:35:53.299 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:375)] - Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=waffle.spring.WindowsAuthenticationToken@5ba0cd13] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@52a70fbd]
2023-04-19 10:35:53.300 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:210)] - Authorized filter invocation [POST /error] with attributes [authenticated]
2023-04-19 10:35:53.301 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:333)] - Secured POST /error
2023-04-19 10:35:53.394 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:375)] - Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=waffle.spring.WindowsAuthenticationToken@5ba0cd13] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@52a70fbd]
2023-04-19 10:35:53.404 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:375)] - Stored SecurityContextImpl [Authentication=waffle.spring.WindowsAuthenticationToken@5ba0cd13] to HttpSession [org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@52a70fbd]
2023-04-19 10:35:53.405 DEBUG [http-nio-8080-exec-2] [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:120)] - Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

Comment: Take a look at this migration guide https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/exploits.html#_i_am_using_a_single_page_application_with_cookiecsrftokenrepository

Comment: @Marcus Hert da Coregio. I tried implementing the solution on the link you provided, but it required me to upgrade pom dependencies spring-security-config and spring-security-web both to 5.8.0. But that ended up breaking other things in the application. I'm using spring-boot-starter-parent 2.7.7 and it's managed versions for spring-security-config (5.7.6), spring-security-web (5.7.6) and spring-security-core (5.7.6). Any solution that could be implemented with those? Thanks.